# is it possible to use Google OAuth without using the google sign in page?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to figure out a way to authenticate using google Oauth without using the google sign in page. I would like to have a separate sign in page for my UI. And my backend will get the email and password from the and authenticate with google. But the problem i'm running into is that when I'm using google oauth it tries to open the google sign in page. Is there a  way to achieve this without using the google sign in page ?

Thank you !

Comment: Would that notnallow your app to steal the user's password? I never enter credentials for another account unless I can see that account site with clear indication that the site is secure and verified via https.

Answer (score 0):

You *really* don't want to do this.  One of the big selling points of OAuth2 is that you can delegate the ownership of identity and credential management.  Users shouldn't give their Google passwords to anyone, except Google :)